# Azure DevOps Free Tier - when "month" starts?

Tags: azure-devops, price

I have Azure DevOps organization with no billing configured. So, it is "free tier".

Microsoft provides 1 Microsoft-hosted parallel job with 1800 minutes/month of execution.

I have spent all of them (now it shows "`Currently 1801/1800 minutes are consumed`").

Ok.

When the minutes are going to be refilled?

I tried to find Organization creation date - and did not succeed.

I expected then that 60 minutes is added daily - no, it stays in this status at least second day.

**Question:** how to understand when the free minutes are going to be refilled?

Comment: Is stated very clear in the Microsoft page:  1800 minutes per month

Comment: Per calendar month? Are the minutes refilled on each 1st of month (1st of Jan, 1st of Feb, 1st of Mar and so on)? Is it reflected somewhere clearly?

Comment: I am pretty sure is per calendar month, but it's been a while. I will try to confirm this tho.

Answer (score 6):

> how to understand when the free minutes are going to be refilled?

For this issue, someone mentioned this in the feedback of the official document, and in this feedback the user found that it is per calendar month.

[image]

For details ,you can refer to [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/3808) in github.